# Is Weaviate compatible with fielded search?

Tags: graphql, weaviate

I'm working with a dataset that contains multiple fields. I need to conduct searches on several fields simultaneously. Is Weaviate compatible with fielded search? If that is the case, I'd appreciate it if you could instruct me on how to combine many search queries.

This is a scheme:

```
  schema = {
        "classes": [{
                "class": "Post",
                "vectorizer": "none", # explicitly tell Weaviate not to vectorize anything, we are providing the vectors ourselves through our BERT model
                "properties": [{
                    "name":"pmid",
                    "dataType": ["int"],
                },
                {
                    "name":"title",
                    "dataType": ["text"],
                },
                {
                     "name": "body",
                    "dataType": ["text"],
                }, 
                {
                    "name":"summary",
                    "dataType": ["text"],
                }]
        }]
    }
```

I'd want to do a simultaneous search on the body and summary. For instance, it identifies publications that have the term "HIV" in their body and summary.

Comment: Do you maybe have a bit more context? Can you share your current schema?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question with more context. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SaeedehKhoshgoftar were you able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. Check out the [`where`-filter](https://www.semi.technology/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/filters.html#where-filter) in the Weaviate docs :-)

Example based on your example schema.

```
{
  Get {
    Post(
      nearVector: {
        vector: [0, 0, 0] # <== your custom vector
      }
      where: { # <== searching for a pmid > 12
        operator: GreaterThan
        valueInt: 12
        path: ["pmid"]
      }
    ) {
      pmid
      title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As far as I am aware, the where is a scalar search. I'm required to vectorize a search over two fields.

Comment: @SaeedehKhoshgoftar ooo but this is very interesting. Can you maybe share a pseudo code example of how you want to do this?

Comment: finds 'pmid' where  'title' is nearVector to 'cancer' AND  'body' is nearVector to 'lung cancer'

Comment: Aha, gotcha! In that case you need to create 2 classes, one where the `pmid` is vectorized and one where `title` is vectorized.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a simple example of how the scheme and vectorized search work? I do not know how I should combine two vectorized searches together in Weaviate.